# How would you compute $\int_0^\infty{\frac{dx}{x^{\frac{2}{5}} (x^2 + 1)^2 }}$.

Tags: calculus, probability, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, stochastic-processes

Given the following integral, how would you solve it?
$$
\int_0^\infty{\frac{dx}{x^{\frac{2}{5}} (x^2 + 1)^2 }}
$$
because $f(x)$ is an even function:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\frac{dx}{2x^{\frac{2}{5}} (x^2 + 1)^2 }}
$$

By Residue integration, we have:
$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)dz = 2 \pi i \sum \text{Res} \{f, z_i \}
$$

The countour $\Gamma$ is:
$$
\Gamma = [\varepsilon, R] \cup\gamma_{R}(0, \pi) \cup [-R, -\varepsilon] \cup \gamma_\varepsilon (-\pi, 0)
$$

[image]

where:
$$
\gamma_r(a, b): \; z =  re^{it} \; \; \; \; t\in (a, b)
$$

hence:
$$
\text{Res} \{f, z = 0 \} = \lim_{z \to 0} \; \; (z - 0) \frac{1}{2z^{\frac{2}{5}} (z^2 + 1)^2 } = 0.
$$

$$
\text{Res} \{f, z = i \} = \lim_{z \to i} \; \; \frac{d}{dz} \left[(z - i)^2\frac{1}{2z^{\frac{2}{5}} (z^2 + 1)^2 } \right] = -\frac{7}{40}e^{3i \pi / 10}
$$

$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)dz = -\frac{7 i \pi}{20}e^{3i \pi / 10}
$$
Now, splitting the integrals:
$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)dz = \int_{\gamma_R} f(z)dz + \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} f(z)dz + \int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon} f(z) dz + \int^{R}_{\varepsilon} f(z) dz
$$

$$
\int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} f(z)dz = \pi i \text{Res} \{f, z = 0 \} = 0
$$

performing the limit where $R \to \infty$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$:
$$
\int_\Gamma f(z)dz  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)dz =  -\frac{7 i \pi}{20}e^{3i \pi / 10}
$$

But this is clearly wrong. I'm doing it right? How should I solve the integral with residues?

Comment: @MarkViola I think you answer is perfectly fine. It just gives you the necesarry hint to finish the rest of the problem by yourself.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Pleased to hear. And please feel free to upvote any answer if you believe it to be useful. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems started at the very beginning, when you claimed the function under the integral is even. Not only it's not even, but note that as a real function it is not even well defined on the negative real axis. You can only define it as a complex function, and that requires choosing a branch.

Your choice of contour is good, and the complex function is $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{\frac{2}{5}}(z^2+1)^2}$, where the chosen branch uses the argument between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$. The only difficulty is to understand the integral on the segment $[-R,-\epsilon]$. For each $t$ in this interval we have, by definition:

$t^{\frac{2}{5}}=e^{\frac{2}{5}\log(t)}=e^{\frac{2}{5}(ln|t|+i\pi)}=(-t)^{\frac{2}{5}}e^{i\pi\frac{2}{5}}.$

That is because $|t|=-t$, and the argument of $t$ on the chosen branch is $\pi$. So after a change of variable, the integral becomes:

$\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{-i\pi\frac{2}{5}}dt}{(-t)^{\frac{2}{5}}(t^2+1)^2}=e^{-i\pi\frac{2}{5}}\int_{\epsilon}^R\frac{dt}{t^{\frac{2}{5}}(t^2+1)^2}\to e^{-i\pi\frac{2}{5}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{\frac{2}{5}}(t^2+1)^2}.$

So all together, the integral over $\Gamma$ tends to $(1+e^{-i\pi\frac{2}{5}})\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$. Now compare with what the residue theorem gives you.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b>0$ then $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^{a-1}}{(1+y)^{a+b}}dy=B(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}.$$ You have also to know $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)\ (*)$ and, for $0<p<1$ $$\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p)=\pi/\sin(\pi p).\ \ (**)$$ Doing $y=x^2$ your integral is
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^{-7/10}}{(1+y)^{2}}dy=\frac{1}{2}B(3/10,17/10)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(3/10)\Gamma(17/10)}{\Gamma(2)}$$$$\stackrel{(*)}{=}\frac{7}{20}\frac{\Gamma(3/10)\Gamma(7/10)}{\Gamma(2)}\stackrel{(**)}{=}\frac{7}{20}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{10})}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=y^5$.  Then,we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^{2/5}(x^2+1)^2}\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \frac{5y^2}{(y^{10}+1)^2}\,dy\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, choose a "pie-shaped" contour that encloses the second-order pole at $z=e^{i\pi/10}$.

Let $R>1$. We assert that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{5z^2}{(z^{10}+1)^2}\,dz&=\int_0^R \frac{5y^2}{(y^{10}+1)^2}\,dy\\\\
&+\int_0^{\pi/5}\frac{5R^2e^{i2\phi}}{(R^{10}e^{i10\phi}+1)^2}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_R^0 \frac{5e^{i2\pi/5}y^2}{(y^{10}+1)^2}\,e^{i\pi/5}\,dy\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{5z^2}{(z^{10}+1)^2}, z=e^{i\pi/10}\right)
\end{align}$$

Now, letting $R\to \infty$, we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2/5}(x^2+1)^2}\,dx=\left(1-e^{i3\pi/5}\right)^{-1}2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{5z^2}{(z^{10}+1)^2}, z=e^{i\pi/10}\right)$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

*Using algebra*

$$I=\int{\frac{dx}{x^{\frac{2}{5}} (x^2 + 1)^2 }}=5\int \frac{ t^2}{\left(t^{10}+1\right)^2}\, dt$$
Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{ t^2}{\left(t^{10}+1\right)^2}=-\frac{3}{25 \left(t^2+1\right)}-\frac{1}{25
   \left(t^2+1\right)^2}+$$ $$\frac{t^6-t^4+2}{5
   \left(t^8-t^6+t^4-t^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{3 t^6-5 t^4+6 t^2-6}{25
   \left(t^8-t^6+t^4-t^2+1\right)}$$

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{3}{25 \left(t^2+1\right)}+\frac{1}{25
   \left(t^2+1\right)^2}\right)\,dt=\frac {7\pi}{100}$$
For the remaining, let $(a,b,c,d)$ be the four complex roots of $$y^4-y^3+y^2-y+1=0$$

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{t^6-t^4+2}{
   \left(t^8-t^6+t^4-t^2+1\right)^2}=$$ $$\frac {A_1}{(t^2-a)^2}+\frac {B_1}{(t^2-b)^2}+\frac {C_1}{(t^2-c)^2}+\frac {D_1}{(t^2-d)^2}$$
Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{3 t^6-5 t^4+6 t^2-6}{
   t^8-t^6+t^4-t^2+1}=$$
$$\frac {A_2}{t^2-a}+\frac {B_2}{t^2-b}+\frac {C_2}{t^2-c}+\frac {D_2}{t^2-d}$$

So, a series of simple integrals since, if $k$ is a complex number
$$\int_0^\infty \frac 1{t^2+k}=\frac{\pi}{2}   \sqrt{\frac{1}{k}}$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac 1{(t^2+k)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{\frac{1}{k^3}}$$ Now, using
$$(a,b)=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4} \pm i \, \sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{8} } $$
$$(c,d)=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4} \pm i \, \sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8} } $$ we end with
$$I=\frac{7}{20} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right) \pi$$

*Even the indefinite integral is not so complicated.*